# Где взять модуль на Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Привет.

Подскажите что-нибудь эффектное, чтобы при навидении на картинки получалось следующее:

[image]

Достаточно будет ссылки!

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы при наведении элемент увеличивался?

Comment: `transform: scale(1.1);`

Comment: В любом случае стили писать надо, иначе поплывет у вас все к чертям. Особенно в разных браузерах

Comment: Я к тому, что есть метод на Jquery где-нибудь в сети, я так бы подстроил его под себя!